# Entity with notes

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I've enabled notes for my Invoice entity according to this doc
https://github.com/oroinc/platform/tree/4.2/src/Oro/Bundle/NoteBundle#how-to-enable-notes-using-migrations

I am wondering if I should also extend Invoice entity with ManyToMany relation?
What I want to achieve is to get notes this way:

```
$invoice->getNotes();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create an extra relation as the migration in the above example already creates it.

You can access and manipulate activities with the `Oro\Bundle\ActivityBundle\Manager\ActivityManager`.